# show columns in CTE returns an error - why?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I have a show columns query that works fine:

```
SHOW COLUMNS IN table
```

but it fails when trying to put it in a CTE, like this:

```
WITH columns_table AS (
SHOW COLUMNS IN table
)

SELECT * from columns_table
```

any ideas why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTE requires select clause and we cannot use SHOW COLUMN IN CTE's and as a alterative use INFORMATION_SCHEMA to retrieve metadata .Like below:

```
WITH columns_table AS (
Select * from INTL_DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='CURRENCIES'
)
SELECT * from columns_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [RESULT_SCAN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html):

> Returns the result set of a previous command (within 24 hours of when you executed the query) as if the result was a table. This is particularly useful if you want to process the output from any of the following:
>
> *SHOW or DESC[RIBE] command that you executed.*

```
SHOW COLUMNS IN ...;

WITH columns_table AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM table(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))
)
SELECT *
FROM columns_table;
```